# Finding original sender of QT forwarded signal

Tags: qt, signals-slots, sender

**My Setup:**
I have one class that only emits signals called class Conn.

All of my QObject classes (A, B, and C) exist in isolation and I don't want them to know about each other at all. However, if class A wants to send some information outside of itself, it must send a signal to the Conn object.

Class B and C both have the access to the Conn object and can themselves decided on whether or not they want to listen to one of Conn's signal.

**My Problem:**
Let's say class A wants to emit the signal in the Conn object called *sig_updateFoo(int)* whenever it updates foo.
Now, let's say class A also wants to connect the *sig_updateFoo(int)* signal to its slot called *slot_FooUpdated(int)* because it also wants to listen for when someone else emits the Conn object's signal.

A logical error occurs when when Class A has the Conn object emit a signal which is also connected to one of its slots.

I need to know if the original emitter was Class A (in which case I will disregard the call), or if it was a different class, which is ok).

**Ideas I have tried:**
If I use QObject::sender() in Class A's slot, I only get a reference the Conn object, not Class A.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In general you would have to pass some form of identifier with each signal emission.  The only functionality Qt offers you in this regard is `sender()`, but as you have found out, it only returns the last sender (unsurprisingly).

However, in this scenario wouldn't it be simpler to just compare the value received by `slot_FooUpdated(int)` to last one sent to the `Conn` object, and only act upon it if the values are different?

Comment: Darn, that's what I suspected.
Class A and Class B might send the same value at the same time. They are completely independent of one another. If I only compared the value, I might be throwing away a value from Class B.
Since they are the same value, I guess it wouldn't matter that much, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Thanks for the help.